# How to tell if Microsoft Works is 32 or 64 bit? Please Help!

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I am trying to convert one of our apps to run on Win7 64 bit from XP 32 bit. One of the things that it uses is Excel to import files. It's a little complicated since it was using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 (Excel). I found Office 14 (2010) has a 64bit version I can download. I downloaded Office 2010 Beta but it didn't seem to install Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0. I found that I could download 2010 Office System Driver Beta: Data Connectivity Components which has the ACE.OLEDB.14 in it but when I try to install it, the installed tells me "You cannot install the 64-bit version of Access Database engine for Microsoft Office 2010 because you currently have 32-bit Office products installed". How do I determine what 32bit office products this is reffering to? My Dell came with Microsoft Works installed. I  don't know if this is 32 or 64 bit. Is there anyway to tell? I don't want to uninstall this if it's not the problem and I'm not sure what else might be the problem.

Any help would be appreciated!
thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 5):

Well, the best way I have found to determine whether an app is 32 or 64 is to do the following

- Open the program
- press Ctrl+Alt+Del to open the task manager (or click start task manager from the security screen)
- Click on the processes tab
- Any process that has a *32 attached to the end of it is a 32-bit application

I don't have any experience with that, specifically, but Works isn't part of the office suite so I don't think that's the problem.  I imagine that you still have some component left over from Office 2007 (or 2003..etc) installed somewhere.  This includes Project, Visio, etc. I've run into this problem before when attempting to install Office 64-bit as even an office 2007 program that was not going to be overwritten was causing problems.

Comment: Chris, Perfect! Just what I was looking for. Big Thanks!!

Comment: Bill, if that answers your question, go ahead and accept as the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark.

Comment: For what it's  worth, he had accepted it before it was migrated.

Comment: If you're using Microsoft's Sysinternals Process Explorer as a replacement for the task manager, you can turn on the "Image type" column (also, "Virtualized" is useful in cases of disappearing data in 64-bit Windows).